# angularjs dropdown with ability to preload data based on entered filter

Tags: angularjs

Is there a component, like a dropdown with the ability to enter text, like autocomplete, but it will not preload all the data at once, but will try to load data based on text entered (to filter-out the rest).

Say, I have 50,000 records in the database, but obviously I dont want to bring all that to the client, by providing text filter, I want to bring only the records that match the filter.

Comment: This may be a good read for you http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element

Answer (score 1):

angular-ui-bootstrap's [typehead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) is the best solution for you.
it support in $http and promises. And, it doesn't include any JQuery or any other libray, only AngularJS.